# Angular animation trigger of component gets lost when datasource changes/component is re-rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

i have a problem faced in my current project i cannot comprehend. I have a code example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yaju9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

The parent component has a table which has an `:enter` animation on the row element:

`app.component.ts:`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideIn', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({
          transform: 'translateX(-10px)',
          opacity: 0,
        }),
        animate('1000ms'),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' }, { name: 'd' }];
  ...
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let d of data" @slideIn>
    <td><app-data [name]="d.name"></app-data></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `<app-data>` component has its own animation:

`data.component.ts`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('colExpTargets', [
      state('collapsed', style({ backgroundColor: 'red' })),
      state('expanded', style({ backgroundColor: 'green' })),
      transition('* <=> *', [animate('500ms')]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  someState = true;
  ...
```

`data.component.html`

```html
<div [@colExpTargets]="someState ? 'collapsed' : 'expanded'">
  <div>{{name}}</div>
  <button (click)="changeState()">Change state</button>
</div>
```

Everything works fine so far, the rows are sliding in and each `<app-data>` instance is in state `'collapsed'` and therefore red:

[image]

But if i change the data source which causes a re-render, e.g. changing the first and last element of the `data[]` array, the `<app-data>` elements are not red anymore (seems like they lost their trigger definition):

[image]

If i remove the `@slideIn` animation trigger from the table, the animation trigger for the `<app-data>` elements work fine even when changing the `data[]`.

I have no idea whats going on here, maybe you guys have an idea what is happening here and how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Weird indeed. As a workaround I would not copy the array, but move items in the original one.

Comment: just a small hint: if you have 2 states, you can skip explicit animation annotation. just `transition('a <=> b', animate('500ms'))` should be enough

Comment: and this hint also fixes your problem, but I didn't debug it enough to find the real root cause

Comment: Changing the state transition to `transition('collapsed <=> expanded', [animate('500ms')]` does not seem to work. Neither in my project nor in the example above. Or did i miss something?

Comment: Its also strange that if i remove the trigger from the parent (sliding in new rows), it works as expected. So the trigger of the parent component seems to be somehow related to the trigger of the child component.

Comment: I worked around the problem by using the trackBy() function using the index for tracking in order to avoid that the DOM-elements are recreated when reordering the table. This is not the ideal solution but it works. But i still believe that this is an issue in Angular when looking into this simple code example which has such a weird behavior.